# Google Ad doesn't display

Tags: adsense

At the bottom of content, I have put two rectangular boxes ad, out of which only one shows up. Is there a restriction on showing ads per page.

Following is my code with credentials removed

```
<div class="bottomAds">
            <div class="rectangle1">
                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-********";
                    /* Rectangle-1 */
                    google_ad_slot = "******";
                    google_ad_width = 336;
                    google_ad_height = 280;
                    //-->
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="rectangle2">
                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-*******";
                    /* Medium-Rectangle */
                    google_ad_slot = "******";
                    google_ad_width = 300;
                    google_ad_height = 250;
                    //-->
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, what do you mean by this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a cap to the frames although you can request more frames you cannot render the same window twice.

Comment: I am not rendering the same window twice. One is an Ad unit with 336x280 and other is 300x250. Whats the cap for ad framing ? Am I limited to three ad spaces per page because this is the fourth frame

Comment: The cap is for 3 ad spaces per page. And that is the reason why the fourth one wasn't displaying.